# Topological group with nonzero Euler characteristic

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-groups

Does there exist a compact, Hausdorff and path-connected topological group $G \neq \{*\}$ whose cohomology $H^*(G;\mathbb{Z})$ is of finite type, and the Euler characteristic $$ \chi(G) := \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (-1)^i rank(H^i(G;\mathbb{Z}))$$ is nonzero? Note that such a $G$ cannot be triangulated, and cannot even be an ANR because of Lefschez fixed point theorem.

Comment: I think this is impossible. It's a corollary of the Peter-Weyl theorem that every compact Hausdorff group is a cofiltered limit of compact Lie groups. I think among these the ones that are path-connected and have cohomology of finite type must themselves be compact Lie groups but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: The problem with actually showing all such groups are Lie groups  seems to  be that checking the no-small-subgroup property must somehow actually use the fact that cohomology is of finite type, and these seem totally unrelated.